# TypeError: userSchema.findById is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is the Schema:

[image]

This is a method that returns array of users:

[image]

The console shows error: line 71 - TypeError: userSchema.findById is not a function

Comment: Please, add more information (shown in the console) so we can fully unserstand the error :)

Comment: I found the problem thank you for your response

Comment: Congratulations :) Please write an answer to your own question so this can might be useful in the future for other people.